# Enabling Button Based on IsChecked of RadioButtons

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple window with three radio buttons and a button. I would like to only enable the button if any one of the three radio buttons has been selected. What is the simplest way to code this? I found the b2v converter methodology, but it doesn't seem like you can have your visibility boolean check done on more than one element at a time (and I need to check if any one of three radio buttons is checked).

Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
<!-- Why No Upgrade Content-->
        <StackPanel Name="WhyNoUpgradeScreen" Visibility="Hidden">
            <TextBlock Text="Sorry You're Not Upgrading to Windows 10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Please let us know why:" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="38" Margin="0 20 0 0" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
            <Grid Margin="0 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <RadioButton Name="NeedWin7RadioButton" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <RadioButton.Content>
                        <TextBlock Text="Need Windows 7 or 8 for my job." TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </RadioButton.Content>
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Name="CantUpgradeRadioButton" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10 0 10 0">
                    <RadioButton.Content>
                        <TextBlock Text="I've tried and can't upgrade." TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </RadioButton.Content>
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Name="OtherRadioButton" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <RadioButton.Content>
                        <TextBlock Text="Other." TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </RadioButton.Content>
                </RadioButton>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Margin="0 30 0 0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Name="BackButton_WhyNoUpgrade" Margin="30 0 150 0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Back" Click="BackButton_WhyNoUpgrade_Click" ></Button>
                <Button Name="SendFeedbackButton_WhyNoUpgrade" Margin="85 0 0 0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Send Feedback" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="SendFeedbackButton_WhyNoUpgrade_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>�
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a trigger for each radio button

this basically says: "enable me when 1st radio is checked OR when 2nd radio is checked OR when 3rd radio is checked"

```
<Button Name="SendFeedbackButton_WhyNoUpgrade" Margin="85 0 0 0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Send Feedback" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="SendFeedbackButton_WhyNoUpgrade_Click" >
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">

      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>

      <Style.Triggers>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=NeedWin7RadioButton}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=CantUpgradeRadioButton}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=OtherRadioButton}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>

      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

note that when you check one RadioButton then button will be enabled permanently, because you cannot uncheck all RadioButtons in a group (not via clicks)

also not that if you are working using MVVM approach and Button has a Command property bound to a viewModel, then Button.IsEnabled will be based on result of `CanExecute` method of that Command